# corrupted frames when returned to a frame array

Tags: c, ffmpeg

when running the following code, I encountered corrupted frames.They were valid frames during frame decoding process,

```
(gdb) print frame->side_data 
$2 = (AVFrameSideData **) 0x1a2ad40
(gdb) print frame->side_data->type 
$3 = AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS
```

however, when they were returned to AVFrame array, I found corrupted frames inside array, which means, the pointers were still there but I couldn't access what the pointers actually pointed to:

```
(gdb) print frames_video1[1]->side_data 
$4 = (AVFrameSideData **) 0x1a21bc0
(gdb) print frames_video1[1]->side_data->type
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

code I think responsible for it has been demonstrated as follows:

```
AVFrame frames_video1[3];
char *src_filename1;

int main()
{
...
    decode_video(src_filename1, frames_video1);
...    
}

int decode_video(char *src_filename, AVFrame frames_video[])
{
...
    video_dec_ctx->flags2 |= AV_CODEC_FLAG2_EXPORT_MVS;
...
    decode_packet(&got_frame, 0, frames_video);
...
}

static int decode_packet(int *got_frame, int cached, AVFrame frames_video[])
{
    int ret = 0;
    int decoded = pkt.size;
    *got_frame = 0;
    if (pkt.stream_index == video_stream_idx) {
            /* decode video frame */
        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(video_dec_ctx, frame, got_frame, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error decoding video frame (%s)\n", av_err2str(ret));
            return ret;
        }
        if (*got_frame) {
            if(video_frame_count < FRAME_TO_COMPARE_NUM){
            AVFrame tmp;
            tmp = *frame; //here I inserted a breakpoint, frames here are still valid...
            frames_video[video_frame_count] = tmp;
        }
        video_frame_count++;
    }
    return decoded;
}
```

can someone perhaps tell me how to soundly return a frame array so that pointers inside a frame are still valid pointers?

I want to hear your response, whether I've not described the issue clearly, so you don't understand it thoroughly, then I'd like to explain it in more detail, or you've not come across this kind of issue before?

Comment: Where is `*frame` coming from in `decode_packet`? I don't see this variable declared anywhere...

Comment: AVFrame *frame; // each frame has been correctly decoded. The problem is when they are collected into an array...and sent back...

Comment: @Kindermann, If you found an answer provided here helpful, please upvote and/or mark as accepted, so that other users with a similar question can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in "frames_video[]" into decode_packet method by value and therefore you can't update it within this method.
Try changing it to pass it around as a pointer to the array.

Comment: That's a much more serious problem: I want to keep AVFrame frames_video[] instead of using AVFrame *frames_video[]

Comment: Well you don't have you use it as a pointer outside of decode_packet, but you will have to send it to the method as pass-by-reference.

Comment: You could change decode_packet to return the updated frames_video[] if you never wanted to use a pointer.

Comment: could you possibly write me the declarations?